# Install-package Entity framework error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, nuget, class-library

I need help.
When i'm trying to install Entity-framework to my class library in my solution, i'm getting an error:

*Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:#work#web\DanceClubCMS\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies.
 Не удается найти указанный файл." =>  **(translate from russian - file not found)**
At D:#work#web\DanceClubCMS\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\install.ps1:10 char:34
+     $appDomain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException*

please help me. How can i fix that problem?

Comment: which version of .NET is the project?

Comment: have you tried restarting visual studio? and are you using a recent version of NuGet

Comment: Yes, I'm using a recent version of nuget. Yes I have. I've tried restarting vs.

Comment: 'file:///D:#work#web\DanceClubCMS\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll this file is exist, and entity framework is installed (I can use datamodels,code-first,etc) , but if i tried to use a code-first migrations, I've always got this error.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was in way to my project 'file:///D:#work#web\'  character '#' its a bad practice... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was in way to my project 'file:///D:#work#web\' character '#' its a bad practice... thanks.